# Ember.js show hasMany data in template with one or more results

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

After endless trying I hope someone find the clue in what I am trying. I know there are many questions about this specific topic on stackoverflow. However I think I do not ask the same question. As I do not find the answer to my specific challenge.

Here is my **Router**:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('article', {path: '/article/:id'});
    this.resource('article.new', {path: "/article/new"});
});
```

**Routes**

```
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('article', params.id);
    }
});

App.ArticleNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render('article', {
            controller: 'article.new'
        });
    },
    model: function () {
        return this.store.createRecord('article');
    }
});
```

The **model**

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string'),
    categoryRelation: DS.belongsTo('category')
});

App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.hasMany('category')
)};
```

The returned **JSON** from server:

```
{
   "articles":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Car 1",
         "category":[1,2],
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Car 2",
         "category":2,
   ],

   "categorys":[ // note the added 's' when returning multiple items as per EmberJS convention
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Oldtimers"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Classic"
      }
   ],
}
```

And now the question, because I try in my template the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="article"> 
    <div>
        {{#each category in model}}
            {{category.name}}<br>
            {{name}}<br>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

I have tried multiple variations in the template, this is my last code which seems correct. Note: as for article with id 2, the template must also render if there is just one article.

Edit: I translated some code for you guys. If there are misspellings, they are probably not in the original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your article template will receive just one article so this `{{#each category in model}}` don't work, you need to use `{{#each category in model.category}}`:

```
<div>
    Article {{name}}<br/>
    {{#each category in model.category}}
        Category {{category.name}}<br/>            
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

This is a fiddle with this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/fj26R/

Comment: Hi Márcio, Many thanks for your answer! However this wont work for a single item. See Article with id 2. Do I need to return a single item as an array from the server?

Comment: I have edited your fiddle to see the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object 2 has no method 'everyProperty'`: http://jsfiddle.net/snmR2/ It is obvious that it expects an array for the each statement. However, is it possible to change the each behavior so that it also will show a single item?

Comment: Yes, change the `"category":2` to `"category":[2]` will solve the problem, and it's the easy way to solve your problem, unless you don't have control over the server side.

Comment: Words cannot express how helpful this answer was.  I'm actually distraught over how simple of an issue this was...